# wget steam local time

Tags: timezone, wget, steam, localtime

When I wget any pages from Steam, the dates listed in them aren't my local time, which they are when I open them in a normal web browser instead. With wget, all the time stamps on the downloaded pages are several hours off, so it seems Steam-pages downloaded by wget assume the wrong time zone somehow.
Any idea how to fix this? I already tried

```
wget --header='Accept-language:xxx'
```

where xxx is a country code, but it didn't change the time zone/stamps, the only effect was that indeed the sites had a different language then.

Comment: Are you calling [the Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) or something else?  Please provide a complete example, including the value you are seeing and what you expect it to be.

Comment: Also, note that country code or language is not a way to select a time zone, as many countries have multiple time zones.   And - it's likely that the values you're seeing are in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).